# IIS7: A process serving application pool 'YYYYY' suffered a fatal communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, windows-server-2008, http-status-code-503

We're running a 32-bit Windows server 2008 with an IIS version of 7.
 We're attempting to publish an asp.net 4.0 webapp and so far our attempts have only yielded a few warnings in the serverlog without even stopping the 4.0 application pool

> **A process serving application pool 'ASP.NET v4.0' suffered a fatal communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service. The process id was '1904'. The data field contains the error number.**

The application is running under a 4.0 app-pool and under the default website. 
We've also got some older .asp's running flawlessly.
Even when attempting to publish a barren (read. only 1 line of text) .aspx-file it failed miserably... We've since long run out of ideas on what to do so any form of input would be appreciated...

Comment: @ScottE Link is dead

Comment: Updated link: http://mvolo.com/troubleshooting-iis7-503-quotservice-unavailablequot-errors-with-startup-debugging/

Comment: In my case, problem was an unlimited recursive loop in my application code.

Comment: I know the post is old, but I've got to say that when I was searching for a solution to my problem, it didn't help. I must say that my problem was related to database users. They didn't have EXECUTION permissions. C-ya.

Answer (score 15):

I was debugging the problem for the better part of the day and when I was close to burning the building I discovered the [Process Monitor tool from Sysinternals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon).

Set it to monitor `w3wp.exe` and check last events before it exits after you fire a request in the browser. Hope that helps further readers.

Comment: Mine was missing nuget packages (System.Net.Primitives in my case)

Comment: In my case, problem was an unlimited recursive loop in my application code.

Comment: I had numerous missing files and a wrong build of some type.  Something wrong with my deploy setup.

Comment: In my case, problem was 'ApplicationPoolIdentity' that did not have read permissions.
see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334216/iis7-permissions-overview-applicationpoolidentity

Comment: For me it was URL Rewrites and Application Request Routing not recognized by IIS.

Comment: It worked, it didn't show an explicit error but the last working operation was an access to %systemroot% that failed

Answer (score 15):

Debug Diagnostics Tool (DebugDiag) can be a lifesaver.  It creates and analyze IIS crash dumps.  I figured out my crash in minutes once I saw the call stack.

[IIS Application Pool Crash and Debug Diag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/parvez/iis-application-pool-crash-and-debug-diag)

Comment: For further information, here's a TechNet blog article showing how to configure the DebugDiag tool to catch a crash dump: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/parvez/2016/08/06/iis-application-pool-crash-and-debug-diag/

Comment: Highly recommend this soluition.  In our case it turned out to be a recursive method.

Answer (score 12):

Make sure that each Application Pool in IIS, under `Advanced Settings` has `Enable 32 bit Applications` set to **`True`**

[image: IIS screenshot]

Comment: Could you please explain why this would solve the OP's issue?  I am asking because I and encountered the same issue on 64-bit Windows Server 2008 R2 and would like to know if this solution can be generalized to my case.  Thank you!

Comment: Same answer given here http://stackoverflow.com/a/7920145/28411, so seems to be something to it. Didn't work for me unfortunately.

Comment: I recently ran into this issue with an ODBC connected product moved to a new server. Flipping the Enable 32-Bit Application to true solved the issue.

Comment: what if i do not want 32-bit apps on the AppPool, and really need 64-Bit? what is the solution for "Run only 64-Bit" scenarios?

Comment: Had the same issue. But this is weird. I switch that setting to true, apply the change, and then, go back and put it to false again and guess what, it is still working... I'm mystify by this...

Comment: This is a red herring, not a solution to the problem.  The problem is whatever is causing the application to fail.

Comment: For me the windows logs showed a problem with virtual memory of the process which could not be increased. I think that setting "Enable 32Bits Application" limits the size of the process at 2GB and simply forces a pool recycle when the limit is reached. You can also set the a virtual memory limit in the advanced parameters of the application pool.

Comment: Downvoting. Stan is right: "The problem is whatever is causing the application to fail." This workaround will cause you some serious headaches if you require the app pool to run 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

When I had this problem, I installed '[Remote Tools for Visual Studio 2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/subscriptions/securedownloads/?#FileId=66305)' from MSDN. I attached my local VS to the server to debug.

I appreciate that some folks may not have the ability to either install on or access other servers, but I thought I'd throw it out there as an option.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this recently. Our organization restricts the accounts that run application pools to a select list of servers in Active Directory. I found that I had not added one of the machines hosting the application to the "Log On To" list for the account in AD.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was a configuration file that was missing an Element.

Answer (score 0):

In our case, the issue was related to using of `app.UseCors(corsOptions)` in `Configuration(IAppBuilder app)` method.
The issue also was accompanied by increase in IIS response times and spike of 502 errors. We don't know how exactly it caused the issue though.