# Reset my w3wp process in different time

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have an ASP.NET application running under IIS. I use Windows Server 2012. I have a big problem. My application resets at different times. When I check the event log, I have just one log:

> A process serving application pool 'Services-Local-System' suffered a
>   fatal communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service.
>   The process id was '7788'. The data field contains the error number.

When I check the log from my app, it doesn't have any logs.
When I check my IIS config, everything is correct.
What is my problem?

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044752/how-do-i-crash-the-app-pool

Comment: maybe it's same (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204444/iis7-a-process-serving-application-pool-yyyyy-suffered-a-fatal-communication)

Comment: This is very hard to find such that code in my project

Comment: Most probably exception(s) in your application is bringing down your app pool. Check if there are any other errors logged in event viewer.