# IIS - Service Unavailable - Stop pool

Tags: asp.net, iis, application-pool

I have IIS where run my WebApp and lately every day several time Stop pool and I get `Service Unavailable HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.`
Then I have to Start pool and WebApp works.
In Server Manager => Events I get this:

```
Application pool 'url' is being automatically disabled due to a series of failures in the process(es) serving that application pool.

A process serving application pool 'url' terminated unexpectedly. The process id was '6360'. The process exit code was '0xc000041d'.

A process serving application pool 'url' terminated unexpectedly. The process id was '9456'. The process exit code was '0xc000041d'.

A process serving application pool 'url' terminated unexpectedly. The process id was '6156'. The process exit code was '0xff'.

A process serving application pool 'url' terminated unexpectedly. The process id was '4964'. The process exit code was '0xc000041d'.

A process serving application pool 'url' terminated unexpectedly. The process id was '10168'. The process exit code was '0xc000041d'.

A process serving application pool 'url' terminated unexpectedly. The process id was '4812'. The process exit code was '0xff'.

A process serving application pool 'url' terminated unexpectedly. The process id was '3776'. The process exit code was '0xc000041d'.

A process serving application pool 'url' suffered a fatal communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service. The process id was '9764'. The data field contains the error number.

A process serving application pool 'url' terminated unexpectedly. The process id was '7656'. The process exit code was '0xc000041d'.

A process serving application pool 'url' suffered a fatal communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service. The process id was '4704'. The data field contains the error number.

Application pool 'url' is being automatically disabled due to a series of failures in the process(es) serving that application pool.

A process serving application pool 'url' terminated unexpectedly. The process id was '3412'. The process exit code was '0xc000041d'.

A process serving application pool 'url' terminated unexpectedly. The process id was '6332'. The process exit code was '0xff'.

A process serving application pool 'url' suffered a fatal communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service. The process id was '1136'. The data field contains the error number.

A process serving application pool 'url' suffered a fatal communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service. The process id was '8716'. The data field contains the error number.
```

What should I do. How can I fix this problem?
Thx.

Comment: You have an error in your application that is causing IIS Rapid-Fail Protection to intervene. You need to find the underlying error. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204444/iis7-a-process-serving-application-pool-yyyyy-suffered-a-fatal-communication.

Comment: Check the event viewer

Comment: @CodeCaster, the solution you have outlined only works if the underlying error is in your code, ASP.NET exceptions are very well logged in event viewers. The only case when they are not logged are things like SSL handshake, third party non .NET code crashing, for which you anyway can't handle errors !!

Comment: application worked fine before we move it to the new server then start this problem