# IIS: Website takes forever to load until I change the HTTPS binding back and forth

Tags: iis

We have a large web application that is hosted on IIS for many customers. We often have the following problem with some customers, but it cannot be reproduced permanently:

After an IIS reset or server restart, the AppPool starts automatically, but when you open the application in the browser, only a white page appears and the browser takes forever to load.

The application can only be accessed again if we change the HTTPS binding from 443 to e.g. 8443 in IIS under "Default Web Site", click OK and then change it back to 443.

The following errors then appear in the EventLog:

"worker process '13952' serving application pool '[ApplicationPoolName]' failed to start a listener channel for protocol 'http' in the allotted time. The data field contains the error number. (B4050780)"

and

"A process serving application pool '[ApplicationPoolName]' suffered a fatal communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service. The process id was '7736'. The data field contains the error number. (6D000780)"

Has anyone had a problem like this or has an idea what it could be?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As the answer below says, when you encounter server hangs, crashes, or CPU performance issues, you can use PerfMon to collect data and DebugDiag for analysis.
But analyzing the dump file is a complex process, so I recommend you to open a support ticket via: https://support.microsoft.com, there will be professional technicians to assist you in grabbing the dump file and analyzing it.

Answer (score 1):

> Has anyone had a problem like this or has an idea what it could be?

The 2011 thread "[IIS7: A process serving application pool 'YYYYY' suffered a fatal communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7204444/6309)" illustrates that others "had a problem like this".

```bash
[Browser] ---HTTPS---> [IIS Server]
                             |
                          [AppPool]
                             |
                  [Application Processing]
```

If the [AppPool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities) or the [listener for HTTP/HTTPS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/introduction-to-iis/introduction-to-iis-architecture#protocol-listeners) is not properly initialized, it can lead to timeouts or endless loading times as described.

The Debug Diagnostics Tool ([DebugDiag](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=103453)) was mentioned as a useful tool for creating and analyzing IIS crash dumps, helping to identify the root cause of crashes more effectively. Tools like [Process Monitor from Sysinternals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) can provide real-time monitoring of file system, Registry, and process/thread activity, offering clues on what might be going wrong just before a crash. See for illustration "[Troubleshooting High CPU in an IIS application pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/health-diagnostic-performance/troubleshoot-high-cpu-in-iis-app-pool)".

Make sure that all necessary configuration files are present and correctly set up. A missing or misconfigured element can cause the application pool to crash.
And confirm that the ApplicationPoolIdentity or any custom identity assigned to your application pool has the necessary permissions, not only on the file system but also in other areas such as the database or any other service it interacts with
In one case, antivirus software was found to be the culprit. Interference by antivirus can cause unexpected behavior in IIS processes. It is worth checking with your IT security team if there is any policy or configuration that might affect the application pools.

More generally, follow the 2016 blog post "[IIS Application Pool Crash and Debug Diag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/parvez/iis-application-pool-crash-and-debug-diag)" by [Parvez N Mulla](https://in.linkedin.com/in/parvez-mulla-77477a98) and "[How to debug w3wp `clr.dll` error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18335759/6309)".

---

> I found the solution: a [WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/wcf/info) service constructor was waiting infinite for a signalR connection.

That is indeed a common issue in web applications and services: synchronous waits or deadlocks caused by improper asynchronous handling or resource locking mechanisms.

When a WCF service constructor indefinitely waits for a [SignalR connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SignalR) (or any external resource), it can lead to application hangs or crashes because the constructor blocks the thread it is running on, preventing the service from completing its initialization and starting properly.
In server environments like IIS, this can manifest as application pools failing to start or respond to requests, leading to the kind of fatal communication errors mentioned.

So it is important to implement non-blocking asynchronous patterns, especially when dealing with I/O operations or inter-process communication like SignalR. In .NET, this often means using `async` and `await` keywords to write asynchronous code that can await operations *without* blocking threads.

```cs
// Example of making the constructor async-await friendly
public class MyWcfService
{
    public MyWcfService()
    {
        InitializeSignalRConnectionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    private async Task InitializeSignalRConnectionAsync()
    {
        // Assume ConnectToSignalRAsync is an async method that connects to SignalR
        await ConnectToSignalRAsync();
        // Further initialization logic here
    }
}
```

That means constructors should be lightweight and not involve lengthy operations. Consider deferring initialization that involves I/O or network calls to an asynchronous initialization method that can be called after the object's construction.

The async-await pattern is used to handle asynchronous operations. That would keep the UI responsive and avoids blocking the thread.

You also need robust error handling for asynchronous operations, and timeouts in place for operations that could hang indefinitely and catch exceptions appropriately to prevent crashes. Plus detailed logging around asynchronous operations and potential blocking points.

Be mindful of thread pool exhaustion and resource management. Excessive blocking or synchronous waits can lead to thread pool starvation, affecting the entire application or server's ability to process requests.