# Application Pool Crashes IIS 10 ASP.Net Core 3.2 Blazor App EF Core

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an `Asp.Net Core 3.2` Blazor Webassembly application that has been published to a server running `Windows Server 2016` with `IIS 10`.

After publishing to the server I can browse the login page to the site, However, when I attempt to login which calls a service and signs in with `Entity Framework Core 3.1.5`.

However when I attempt to call a linq query on the `DbContext` it seems to fail (This is deduced from log files).

Interestingly, if I remote into the server whilst running a login I get a JIT popup with the following error;

[image: JIT Popup Server]

In the Windows System Log can see the following error;

> A process serving application pool 'myapppool(domain)(4.0)(pool)' suffered a fatal communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service. The process id was '10188'. The data field contains the error number.

It seems to sometime crashes the apppool as well so if I then refresh the page i get 502 error on the site?

Below is a screen shot of the application pool advanced settings;

[image: application pool screenshot]

The server is running Windows 2016 with Plesk Obsidian installed on it (I'm not sure if this can interfere in any way??)

Does anyone know whats going on here please?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know what’s going on since I can not reproduce your issue. Here is a workaround.
Please ensure that IIS Application pool’s `Advanced Settings` has set ”`Enable 32-Bit Application`” to `true`.
[image]
Check below link for troubleshooting the issue.
[How to diagnose IIS fatal communication error problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207617/how-to-diagnose-iis-fatal-communication-error-problem/7920145#7920145)

Comment: Thank you for the link, I've updated the question to include a screen for the application pool being used, along with a bit more info on the server (which has a plesk admin installed as well).

Comment: Who cares about Win32 on x64 servers?? This is not a workaround...
Microsoft says that for years!
It is more like: solve itching of your hand by chopping it OFF!!!